# How to detect UserAgent within an NPAPI plug-in before it is registered by the browser?

Tags: safari, npapi

I need to figure out a way to install plug-ins specifically for Safari on Mac. If I copy the `.plugin` files into the `Internet Plug-ins` folder, it will be detected by Firefox and Google Chrome as well when they are run.

To prevent this I was using the `NP_UserAgent` API call to determine the user agent, and exit if it wasn't Safari. However the plug-ins are still registered by Google Chrome and Firefox. Is there anyway to do the same thing without having either browser register the plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing an NPAPI plugin it should work in any browser. Can you explain why you are trying to prevent users running other browsers from using the plugin? Depending on the underlying need there may be a better approach. (For instance, if this is to work in conjunction with a Safari extension, all you need to do is have your extension use a MIME type that only your plugin handles, and then it doesn't matter if other browsers detect the plugin because it will never actually be instantiated).

Do you want to target *only* Safari, or any browser using Apple's WebKit framework? If the latter, you could write a [WebKit plugin](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/Tasks/WebKitPlugins.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001249-BAJGJJAH) instead of an NPAPI plugin.

Comment: Thanks @smorgan... Think this is how I'll move forward. Yes, your guess is absolutely right... The plug-ins do work in conjunction with a Safari extension. It is actually an existing extension for Firefox and Chrome and I'm trying to port it to Safari. Yes if you like it :) http://www.cloudmagic.com/

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to detect browser with JavaScript and insert `<object>` tag into HTML page only if it's Safari. But of course, it doesn't prevent the plugin from being registered.

Another way is to write WebKit plugin for Safari. It's even easy to implement than NPAPI.